# Unity3d | строка из Input field TMP (string) библиотеке не совпадает с текстом

Tags: c#, unity3d, строки, unity3d-ui

По части кода я не понимаю, почему не работает совпадение с текстом из `InputField (TextMeshPRO)`, к примеру "Hello"

```
TextMeshProUGUI textInput = transform.Find("Description/InputField (TMP)/Text Area/Text").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
string str = textInput.text;

if (str.Equals("Hello"))
        {
            Action(str);
            DestroyMe();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log($"str = {str.GetHashCode()}, and Hello = {"Hello".GetHashCode()}");
        }
```

При вводе "Hello" и запуске скрипта у меня не срабатывает первое условие (хотя должно), и появляется в консоли это (для проверки на совпадение использовал `GetHashCode()`): `str = 652893137, and Hello = -327378614`. Возможно опять новый TextMeshPRO что-то не то делает (уже столько багов у этого скрипта), но посоветуйте пожалуйста (не нужно просто писать: "Не используй функции TextMeshPRO"), что с этим можно сделать?

Заранее спасибо

UPD: Я заметил, что он даже если в поле ввода ничего не ввести и сделать проверку на `if (str.Length == 0), он её обойдёт тоже!`

Comment: `str == "Hello"` тоже не работает? а то что хеши разные, это и так понятно, вы сравниваете хэш объекта (строки) и константы "Hello". ХэшКод строится не по содержимому, если что.

Comment: Тоже не работает (уже пробовал изначально, поэтому и попробовал `Equals()`)

Comment: Ну если не работает, значит не равно. `Debug.Log(str)`

Comment: Ну знаешь, так просто ответить "Значит не работает". Я пробовал обычный стандартный UI InputField и всё работает нормально.<p>
TextMeshPro - это официальный от Unity, который должен быть лучше стандартной UI, но что то пошло не так у них с ошибками. Поэтому я и спрашиваю тут, как без замены на стандартный UI сравнить строки

Comment: Я же написал `Debug.Log(str)`, и смотрите, что там внутри. Вдруг там вообще пусто?

Comment: В том то и дело, что если в InputField я напишу "Hi", он в Debug.log(str) выведет "Hi". Но именно в консоли `str.Equals("Hi")` не будет равно

Comment: Может там перенос строки или пробел? Попробуйте `str.Trim() == "Hi"`

Comment: Не работает. Всё равно пропускает

Comment: Используйте отладку, ставьте точку останова, и смотрите, что там в переменных, выполняя код пошагово. Не может быть такого, что 2 одинаковые строки не равны.

Comment: Я допускаю, что TextMeshPro как то видоизменяет или имеет свой язык. К примеру, я пишу слово "Hi" на английском, а он конвертирует в свой язык (типо к примеру язык "TextMeshProFonts") и поэтому он не может их сравнить

Comment: Короче изменил всё на стандартный UI в Unity. Всё работает отлично, так и оставлю

Comment: а в какой момент мы делаете эту проверку? Вы привели код, но не показали где он вызывается. Может вы делаете проверку просто в Update вместо реакции на событие ввода. Не исключаю, что TMP хранит введённые символы в массиве чаров и сохраняет, как строку только когда ввод закончен, чтобы избежать выделения множества мусорных строк во время ввода

Answer (score 0):

Следует вводить не `TextMeshProUGUI`, который просто вводит символы, а писать `TMP_Text`

```
TMP_Text textInput = transform.Find("Description/InputField (TMP)/Text Area/Text").GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
string str = textInput.text;

if (str.Equals("Hello"))
        {
            Action(str);
            DestroyMe();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log($"str = {str.GetHashCode()}, and Hello = {"Hello".GetHashCode()}");
        }
```